# How to call a function when a SyncFusion grid row is selected

Tags: vue.js, datagrid, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

Using a SyncFusion Vue Grid component, I need to call a function when a row is selected. I have tried adding a column of edit buttons but I can't find documentation for the correct syntax to use to get the buttons to call a function. I also tried looking for a way to just call a function whenever the row itself is clicked which would be fine as long as I can determine which row was clicked (access the value of one of the fields in the row). The [Grid Selection API](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/api/grid/selection/) looks like it is just for programmatically selecting parts of the grid which is not what I am trying to do. I tried following [this explanation](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/144261/data-grid-and-button) but I could not figure out the syntax for getting the button to call a function. I have looked at the Vue and SyncFusion documentation but I can't find specifically what I am trying to do. Below are the relevant parts of the code.

```
<template>
<ejs-grid>
    <e-columns>
        <e-column
            headerText='Buttons'
            width='120'
           :template='cTemplate'></e-column>
        <e-column
            field="name"
            headerText="Name"
            :isPrimaryKey="true"
            width="60"
            ></e-column>
        <e-column
            field="generalSubject"
            headerText="Subject"
            width="40"
            ></e-column>
    </e-columns>
</ejs-grid>
</template>

<script>
export default Vue.extend({  
  data() {
    cTemplate: function () { 
        return { template : Vue.component('columnTemplate',{ 
            template: `<button v-on:click="fx">Edit</button>`, // <-- call fx() syntax??
                data: function() { 
                    return { 
                        data: {} 
                    } 
                },
        })}
    },
    fx: function() { // do something },
  },  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be achieved by using the Grid’s rowSelected event. This event gets triggered on selecting a Grid row and returns the current row details in the event arguments.

Please find the below sample prepared based on this for your reference,

**Sample:** https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-forked-0knlb?file=/src/App.vue

**API link:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/api/grid/#rowselected

Let us know if you need further assistance.

Regards,

Sujith R